# Replace function not replacing

Tags: javascript, regex

I followed some documentation to use the JavaScript replace function and it's not changing anything. No errors are thrown. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The variable is retrieved from XML - maybe it needs to be cast as a string or something?

```
for (var i = 0, iln = projects.length; i < iln; i++){
    var thumb = projects[i].get('thumb');
    thumb.replace("200.jpg", "640.jpg");
    console.log(thumb) //200.jpg not replaced
}
```

The full thumb value should look like this:

```
http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/160/895/160895498_200.jpg
```

Is there a better way to find and replace things?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assign the value back into `thumb`.

```
thumb = thumb.replace("200.jpg", "640.jpg");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
thumb = thumb.replace("200.jpg", "640.jpg");
```