# JavaScript string replace is not working

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript replace function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429321/javascript-replace-function-not-working)

Here is my JS code:

```
var imgTitle = "fizz";
var imgTitle2 = "fizz";
var imgInfo = "buzz";
var imgSrc = "foo";
var liHTML = "<li class='imgThumbLi ui-draggable' title='IMG_TITLE'><img class='image' src='IMG_SRC' title='IMG_TITLE'/><div class='imageInfo'><p class='detailTitle'>IMG_INFO</p></div></li>";

// Search and replace all dummy values.
liHTML.replace("IMG_TITLE", imgTitle);
liHTML.replace("IMG_TITLE2", imgTitle2);
liHTML.replace("IMG_SRC", imgSrc);
liHTML.replace("IMG_INFO", imgInfo);

alert(liHTML);
```

Getting this for print out:

```
 <li class='imgThumbLi ui-draggable' title='IMG_TITLE'><img class='image' src='IMG_SRC' title='IMG_TITLE'/><div class='imageInfo'><p class='detailTitle'>IMG_INFO</p></div></li>
```

(Same as before the string replace calls). In Firebug I'm getting an error stating:

> c.replace is not a function

Get this error anytime the code snippet above executes. **Why isn't this string replace working?!?!** Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strings are immutable. And the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is clear: *"This method does not change the String object it is called on. It simply returns a new string."* Why did you think `.replace()` would work in-place?

Comment: where is the placeholder for `IMG_TITLE2`?

Comment: Ah... you are also getting an error. What is `c`? The error does not relate to the code you posted.

Comment: sometimes javascript doesn't update instantly - you might wanna try - 

liHTML = liHTML.replace("IMG_TITLE", imgTitle); //and then alert

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try

```
liHTML = liHTML.replace("IMG_TITLE", imgTitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the new value on every line.

```
liHTML = liHTML.replace("IMG_SRC", imgSrc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything with the replaced values. Try:

```
var imgTitle = "fizz";
var imgTitle2 = "fizz";
var imgInfo = "buzz";
var imgSrc = "foo";
var liHTML = "<li class='imgThumbLi ui-draggable' title='IMG_TITLE'><img class='image' src='IMG_SRC' title='IMG_TITLE'/><div class='imageInfo'><p class='detailTitle'>IMG_INFO</p></div></li>";

// Search and replace all dummy values.
liHTML = liHTML.replace("IMG_TITLE", imgTitle);
liHTML = liHTML.replace("IMG_TITLE2", imgTitle2);
liHTML = liHTML.replace("IMG_SRC", imgSrc);
liHTML = liHTML.replace("IMG_INFO", imgInfo);

alert(liHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the results in the variable liHTML:

```
liHTML = liHTML.replace("IMG_TITLE", imgTitle);
liHTML = liHTML.replace("IMG_TITLE2", imgTitle2);
liHTML = liHTML.replace("IMG_SRC", imgSrc);
liHTML = liHTML.replace("IMG_INFO", imgInfo);
```

// EDIT
Ups a bit to slow :D

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of problems there. First of your not setting the value. Replace just generates new value. Second problem is that in your case you should probably use replace-all instead of replace.

Replace replaces only the first instance.

```
// Scope should have one var. Combine those vars.
var imgTitle = "fizz",
    imgTitle2 = "fizz",
    imgInfo = "buzz",
    imgSrc = "foo",
    liHTML = "<li class='imgThumbLi ui-draggable' title='IMG_TITLE'><img class='image' src='IMG_SRC' title='IMG_TITLE'/><div class='imageInfo'><p class='detailTitle'>IMG_INFO</p></div></li>";

// Search and replace all dummy values.
liHTML = liHTML.replace(new RegExp("IMG_TITLE", 'g'), imgTitle);
liHTML = liHTML.replace(new RegExp("IMG_TITLE2", 'g'), imgTitle2);
liHTML = liHTML.replace(new RegExp("IMG_SRC", 'g'), imgSrc);
liHTML = liHTML.replace(new RegExp("IMG_INFO", 'g'), imgInfo);

alert(liHTML);
```